# getting data from 2 tables and writing a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am having trouble with a query in php. I don't seem to get the output that I am wanting to get.
The query that I am trying to write is

> For each country, list the largest population of any of its cities and
>   the name of that city. Order the results in decreasing order of city populations.

Here is the code that I tried, along with the table that I tried:

```
SELECT MAX(population) as population, name
FROM what.city
ORDER BY population DESC
```

Here are the tables that I am using:

```
               Table "what.country"
     Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0
 life_expectancy | real                  | 
 gnp             | real                  | 
 gnp_old         | real                  | 
 local_name      | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
 government_form | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
```

---

```
               Table "what.city"
    Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                    
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
 population   | integer               | not null default 0
```

Comment: Ur missing group by. SELECT MAX(population) as population, name FROM what.city group by name ORDER BY max(population) DESC

Comment: It's helpful if you expand in " don't seem to get the output that I am wanting to get". i.e. tell us an error if you get one or describe what you are getting vs what you expect.

Comment: @jimmy, can you unaccept my answer, Erwin has correct answer matching ur output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect. One simple and fast way (among others) to achieve this in Postgres is with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT co.name AS country_name, ci.city_name, population
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (country_code)
          country_code, name AS city_name, population
   FROM   what.city
   ORDER  BY country_code, population DESC
   ) ci
JOIN  what.coutry co USING (country_code);
```

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: how to delete my answer, I was only helping with his query but your answer is helping the OP get what they want

Comment: @radar: You can't delete an accepted answer. I flagged it for moderator attention. They will help out.